# How to get place order data in shopify in my private app

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

My name is Waqas Hussain. I'm working on **Shopify App in PHP** in which I need order detail like when a user places an order then I want to get that **specific order data just like Woocommerce place_an_order_hook**. Is it any way to get that data in **Shopify** or **any other solution you want to suggest**?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the [webhook API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook) from Shopify to resolve the issue, there is webhook generated along with data once the specific event occurs and I think you able to get the required data.

[image]